# How should Zend_Validator_StringLength extended?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

How should  Zend_Validator_StringLength extended?
**MyValidator:**

```
class Zend_Validate_StringLengthNoTags extends Zend_Validate_StringLength {

    public function  __construct($options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function isValid($value) {
        return parent::isValid(trim(strip_tags($value)));
    }
}
```

**Use of validator** - bug not assign values to $this->_min, $this->_max:

```
$text->addValidator(new Zend_Validator_StringLengthNoTags(array('max'=>4,'min'=>2)));
```

Edit:

root of bug:      `$this->_min==1, $this->_max==null` ,
but it should be

```
$this->_min==2, $this->_max==4
```

**Update**: the answer:
This was internal application system problem that generate this bug, it fixed soo the code above working. Thanks for all peaple they try to help me.

Thanks

Comment: _min and _max aren't getting assigned or you want to remove them?

Comment: they are not getting assigned

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this custom validator. Do you want to validate length of input string after removing of html tags?

Comment: yes Marchin, I want to validate length of input string after removing of html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your Zend_Validate_StringLengthNoTags could be replaced simply by filters StripTags and StringTrim and standard Zend_Validate_StringLength validator.

For example, I think that the following would work the same as your validator:

```
   $text->setFilters(array('stripTags','stringTrim'));
   $text->addValidator(new Zend_Validator_StringLength(array('max'=>4,'min'=>2)));
```

The reason is that validation in Zend Framework is performed after filtering, i.e. on filtered data.

Returning to your Zend_Validate_StringLengthNoTags code. The code looks ok and  I cannot spote a problem with it.

Comment: thanks, but It can not replaced by filter, I wanr to remove html tags for validation and not for something else. The input should be stored in data base with html tags

Comment: I, too, don't see a problem with the validator as written. Of course, the difference between adding `StripTags` as a filter and using his validator is in the value he gets when he ultimately calls `$form->getValues()`. If added as a filter, the the tags will be stripped. If the filtering is done only in the validator, then the tags will still be there.

Comment: @Yosef. Ok, now I understand.

Comment: @David Weinraub. Yes, now I see what Yosef is trying to do. But still I cannot see whats wrong with code of Zend_Validate_StringLengthNoTags. I even copied this validator to my own project and it works as it supposed.

Comment: Indeed. Sure looks like it ought to work. Anyway, looks like he found the answer and you got an accept out of it. Win, win! ;-)